# Argmax of sum of log functions

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, maximum-likelihood

I am trying to find the below with the context that each $\pi_s$ is a probability. (Trying to assign probabilities so I get maximum likelihood)

$$\underset{\bf{\pi}}{\operatorname{argmax}} \ \sum_{s} c_s * ln(\pi_s)$$
with constraint of
$$\sum_{s} \pi_s=1$$

$c_s$ is integer constants. 
We can assume non-zero pi values if needed.

I tried AM-GM inequality as below:
$$\underset{\bf{\pi}}{\operatorname{argmax}} \ \sum_{s} c_s * ln(\pi_s)$$
$$=\underset{\bf{\pi}}{\operatorname{argmax}} \ \sum_{s} ln(\pi_s^{c_s})$$
$$=\underset{\bf{\pi}}{\operatorname{argmax}} \  ln(\prod_{s}\pi_s^{c_s})$$
$$=\underset{\bf{\pi}}{\operatorname{argmax}} \  \prod_{s}\pi_s^{c_s}$$
$$\le\underset{\bf{\pi}}{\operatorname{argmax}} \  (\frac{1}{|s|}\sum_s\pi_s^{c_s})^{|s|}\  \text{by AM_GM inequality}$$

So, now I know it is maximum when it is equal, but I got stuck here...
Not sure if it's the right approach or not.
Please help and thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried AM-GM inequality by changing the sum of logs to log of products of $\pi$ -> upper bounding the products of $\pi$s by sum of $\pi$s . But I got stuck there..

Comment: It would be better to include this attempt in the post (see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)).

Comment: Hi Aig, I'm sorry I am new to this forum. I have updated my question. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write down the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L}(\pi, \lambda) = \sum_{s} c_{s}\ln(\pi_{s}) + \lambda (\sum_{s}c_{s} - 1)$$

Setting the gradient of $\mathcal{L}$ wrt $\lambda$ and $\pi$ to zero while enforcing the problem constraints yields

$$\pi_{s} = \frac{c_{s}}{\sum_{t}c_{t}}$$

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!! By any chance, do you know whether it would be possible to use AM-GM inequality to solve it?

Comment: I think the AM-GM should read $\prod_s \pi_{s}^{c_{s}} \leq (\frac{\sum_{s}c_{s}\pi_{s}}{\sum_{s} c_{s}})^{\sum_{s}c_{s}}$, maybe that's why you're stuck?

Comment: Ok I will try again. Thanks for your help